# What are the respective uses of TextBlock.FontSize and TextElement.FontSize attached properties?

Tags: wpf, xaml, dependency-properties, attached-properties

Let's say I want to use inheritance of `FontSizeProperty` within a `StackPanel`. I can use:

```
<StackPanel TextBlock.FontSize="15">
    <Label Content="This label uses the same font size..." />
    <ListBox>
        <ListBoxItem Content="...than this item..." />
        <ListBoxItem Content="...and this one." />
    </ListBox>
<StackPanel>
```

However I could also write:

```
<StackPanel TextElement.FontSize="15">
```

which uses a different dependency property. I don't see if there are specific use cases for each (attached) dependency property, and even less what is expected to happen for the `Label` child if they are both used, i.e.

```
<StackPanel TextElement.FontSize="20">
    <StackPanel TextBlock.FontSize="15">
        <Label Content="This label uses the same font size..." />
```

Comment: These are actually not two different properties, but just two different identifiers for the same dependency property. Take a look at the [TextBlock class in the reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/TextBlock.cs,f469b4aeb3697bb8). You'll find `public static readonly DependencyProperty FontSizeProperty = TextElement.FontSizeProperty.AddOwner(typeof(TextBlock));`

Comment: @Clemens: You're right. Do you know why this is done this way? what benefits of having two accesses exceed the confusion created by two accesses?

Comment: Certainly because although it's registered as an attached property, it's widely used like a regular, non-attached dependency property. Since TextBlock and TextElement are not derived from each other, both should be registered as owner type.

Comment: @Clemens: I'm now reading the same mechanism exists also for [Control.FontSizeProperty](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Control.cs,c8d2ef2e2ec9f087) in [WPF 4.5 Unleashed, page 74](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/9780672336973/samplepages/0672336979.pdf)